# How can I re-arrange orders of lines based on alphabet in Python

Tags: python

I have a very large txt file (>1GB), it contains about 8 million items, each item have three words separated with an empty space " ". An example is shown below:

```
Antonym abbreviate elongate
InstanceOf george_toma person
AtLocation cruelty war
NotCapableOf plant speak_to_human
RelatedTo note single
DerivedFrom translatorese ese
Antonym baby elder
Antonym able cane
```

What I want to obtain is a file that re-arrange all items based on the alphabet of the first word - second word - third word. the result should be :

```
Antonym abbreviate elongate
Antonym able cane
Antonym baby elder
AtLocation cruelty war
DerivedFrom translatorese ese
InstanceOf george_toma person   
NotCapableOf plant speak_to_human
RelatedTo note single
```

Is there any easy way to do it with Python? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting alphabetically by words is the same as sorting alphabetically by lines, so:

```
with open('infile_name','r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    lines.sort()
    output_file = open('outfile_name', 'w')
    output_file.writelines(lines)
```

This code will probably take a while for such a large file.

Edited to reflect [limasxgoesto0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038783/limasxgoesto0)'s point:

```
with open('infile_name','r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda s: s.upper())
    output_file = open('outfile_name', 'w')
    output_file.writelines(sorted_lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

The other solution doesn't work if you have mixed cases in your file, as it sorts by order which the characters are represented in memory.  This means your capitals will come before your lower cases (in OP's case, there only seem to be upper cases, so it may be okay, but we don't know the full dataset).

Ex.

```
In [2]: sorted(['a', 'b', 'B', 'A'])
Out[2]: ['A', 'B', 'a', 'b']
```

`sorted()` has another param, key, which lets you change the method which each letter is compared.  So if you convert each to upper case, you'll see it's sorted case insensitively:

```
In [6]: sorted(['a', 'B', 'b', 'A'], key=lambda s:s.upper())
Out[6]: ['a', 'A', 'B', 'b']
```